# FileReference.download() works for .jpg .txt but not .dgn files in flex

Tags: apache-flex

In downloading files using the following codes, it surprised me that it succeeded in downloading .jpg .txt files BUT .dgn format file return IO Error #2038

Could somebody give me any advice? Thanks in advance.

```
        protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            fileRef = new FileReference();
            fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, doEvent);
            fileRef.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, doEvent);
            fileRef.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, doEvent);
            fileRef.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, doEvent);
        }

        private function doEvent(evt:Event):void 
        {
            var fr:FileReference = evt.currentTarget as FileReference;

            switch (evt.type)
            {
                case "complete":
                    Alert.show("File : " + fr.name + " download succeed");
                    break;
                default :
                    Alert.show("Error occur during downloading !!!");
                    break;
            }


        protected function downLoadLICMap(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            urlReq = new URLRequest("http://svygis/viewphoto/ceddphoto/20130916 raw/1se19d.dgn");
            fileRef.download(urlReq);
        }
```

Comment: Rather a server setting: does it have a mime type configured for the .dgn extension? Have you tried opening that URL directly in the browser? (On a side note: there's a space in that URL; not a very good idea)

Comment: I added MIME type "application/octet-stream" for dgn files and it works properly. Thank you very much

Comment: How can I mark your advice as answer? I am new here

Comment: I posted it as a real answer. You can now use the green checkmark next to it to mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect Flex is not at fault here. It would rather be a server setting issue.
Have you tried opening that URL directly in the browser? You probably will not be able to download the file like that either.

If that's the case, you only need to **configure a mime type for the .dgn extension on your web server**.